# Upgrade from Server 2003 to Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a x64 2003 server and want to upgrade to x64 2008 server.  Can this be done as an inplace upgrade or do I need to blow the machine away with a fresh OS install?  The 2003 machine has SQL, IIS, and several VMs.

What are my options?  What are pros and cons for in-place upgrade vs new install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's SP2 R2 you can do an in-place upgrade ([I believe](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/migration-paths.aspx)).  However, I can not stress strongly enough what a bad idea this is.  A fresh build is the best way forward

Comment: Agreed.  Too many horror stories start with "this will be so quick & easy if I can pull off the upgrade..."

Answer (score 0):

Only do an in-place upgrade for the following scenarios:

1) The server has a very plain vanilla configuration with all the defaults still set and no additional software is installed.

2) The cost of re-configuring the server after a clean-install outweighs the cost of having to iron out any legacy 2003 settings that may have adverse effects in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I did an in-place upgrade of 2003 R2 x64 to 2008 x64 because it was in the datacenter and I wanted to minimize my time in the batcave. It had SQL Server and some other little things on it; 6 months later, no difficulties so far.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with O.S. Upgrades being a Bad Thing, particularly between really different systems like 2003 and 2008 (they're different just like XP and Vista, don't forget that).